# Coldfusion equivalent function of codePointAt

Tags: coldfusion

In javascript there is a function [codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) which returns A number representing the code point value of the character at the given index. Is there a UDF or built in function similar to codePointAt function?

```
var icons = '☃★♲';

console.log(icons.codePointAt(0));
// expected output: "9733"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [`asc()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/asc.html) in ColdFusion. The function only converts a single (the first) character though, so you have to extract the position of the desired character in a string by yourself, using [`mid()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/mid.html) for example.

```
<cfscript>

    icons = '☃★♲';
    icon = mid(icons, 2, 1);

    writeOutput( asc(icon) );
    // expected output: "9733"

</cfscript>
```

Comment: As seen on: https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=038429db-bec2-49d2-9ab3-1b62b1219150/ce15e55c-45f4-4fa6-bca1-068791fe3cc1/c999691c-3b01-4c7f-bb59-e830f13eaabc.cfm

Comment: How do you get it to work for multiple character sequences like "".  (It looks like 7 characters, but it's actually 14.)